# Continue an operation even the app get into suspended or terminated state

Tags: c#, uwp, uwp-xaml, xamarin.uwp

I'm new to the UWP, and I'm facing right now an issue where I want to continue an operation that the app was doing before getting into suspended or terminated state.

I've read about Extended execution and background task, but as far as I have understood for extended execution you have only 30 seconds before it gets terminated or it could be revoked before getting into it.

for Background task I should make another project for it ( Windows Runtime Component) and I have to add an entry in the Declarations in the appxmanifest. It sounds that Background task is the only possible way to achieve it, but how to move an operation (Action, Func, or task or whatever) to background task if the app get into those states and what should happen after resume?!

Any ideas from experienced people?

Comment: What kind of task or action do you want to do in background? Why do you need the code to run after the app suspend? Any specific reason or specific request, can you share more details? A classic sample is that we need to keep the network communication in background, for this we have specific trigger, like [SocketActivityTrigger](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/networking/network-communications-in-the-background)  So what's yours?

Answer (score 1):

**Windows 10 universal Windows platform (UWP) app lifecycle**

Before Windows 8, apps had a simple lifecycle. Win32 and .NET apps are either running or not running. Now, there are three app model in UWP app **Running in foreground**,**Running in background** and **suspended state**. You could know more detail through this [official document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/launch-resume/app-lifecycle).

**Extended execution**

> There are cases where an app may need to keep running, rather than be suspended, while it is minimized. If an app needs to keep running, either the OS can keep it running, or it can request to keep running.

For this scenario, you need use `ExtendedExecution` to realize. `ExtendedExecution` support to start a long running operation in order to defer the Suspending state. And there are some [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/launch-resume/run-minimized-with-extended-execution) and [code sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/ExtendedExecution) introducing this feature.

**Background Task**

For `Background Task`, it provide functionality when your app is **suspended** or **not running**. You can also use background tasks for real-time communication apps like VOIP, mail, and IM. However, it will trigger under specific conditions. For more please refer [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/launch-resume/support-your-app-with-background-tasks).

You have mentioned out-process `Background Task` in your case and another `Background Task`[(in process)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/launch-resume/create-and-register-an-inproc-background-task) could also be used in UWP app. It is simpler to implement than out-of-process background tasks.